# Finding a Minimal set of vertices that satisfy the given constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, time-complexity, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

**Note:** no need for formal proof or anything, just the general idea of the algorithm and I will go deeper myself.

Given a **directed** graph: `G(V,E)`, I want to find the smallest set of vertices `T`, such that for each vertex `t` in `T` the following edges don't exist: `{(t,v) | for every v outside t}` in `O(V+E)`

In other words, it's allowed for `t` to get edges from vertices outside `T`, but not to send.

(You can demonstrate it as phone call, where I am allowed to be called from outside and it's free but it's not allowed to call them from my side)

---

I saw this problem to be so close or similar to finding all strongly connected components (scc) in a directed graph which its time complexity is `O(V+E)` and I'm thinking of building a new graph and running this algorithm but not totally sure about that.

Comment: is my question stated clearly, I am not getting any comments or answers I would like to know what's the problem

Comment: The title doesn't match the description in the body of the question. Specifically, the problem statement given in the body doesn't require `T` to be a strongly connected component.

Comment: @user3386109 can you help me choose a better title, plus I know it doesn't require T to be a strongly connected component but I said it's nearly the same (like half strongly connected component) so I am sure we somehow can use the algorithm to find SCC on some edited graph

Comment: Perhaps it's best to keep the title vague, and let the body fill in the details. Something like "Finding a minimal set of vertices that satisfy the given constraints".

Comment: The smallest such `T` is the empty set. (I think there are other constraints that you haven't described?)

Answer (score 2):

The main idea is to contract each strongly connected component (SCC) of G into a single vertex while keeping a score on how many vertices were contracted to create each vertex in the contracted graph (condensation of G). The resulting graph is a directed acyclic graph. The answer is the vertex with lower score among the ones with out-degree equal 0.

The answer structure is an union of strongly connected components because of the restriction over edges and you can prove that there is only a SCC involved in the answer because of the min restriction.

Comment: Hi, your idea won't work since the answer isn't necessarly a strongly connected component. (edges can come from outside the SCC which is against the definition of SCC)

Comment: @john A vertex of a strongly connected component can have incoming xor outcoming edges to vertices of other strongly connected components. E.g: G({1, 2, 3, 4}, {<1, 2>, <2, 1>, <3, 1>, <2, 4>}), there are 3 SCC ({1, 2}. {3}. {4}), the answer to the problem is {4} and there is an edge that come from outside such SCC (<2, 4>).